# Dropdown and MySQl

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown I dynamically populated from mysql
When I save the information it to mysql, it do not save the value of the dropdown list.
How do I set the selected value for the dynamic dropdown
Here is the code use to fill the dropdown.
How do I set the selected value on change in php

```
echo "<option value=\"" . utf8_encode($row['school_name']) . "\">" . utf8_encode($row['school_name']) . "</option>";
```

im have problems setting the correct format using this example

```
<option value="My School"<?php if ($row[school_name] == 'My School') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>My School</option>
```

Where My School should be the value populated from database

Ok

```
   <select id="school_name" "name="school_name" style="width:200px;" name="school_name">
                        <option selected="">Select Province School</option>



                        </select>
```

i then fill the dropdownlist with following.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ppSD_schools where province_code ='".$_POST['c_id']."'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $res->num_rows;

if($num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())

    {
    ?>
        echo "<option value=\"" . utf8_encode($row['school_name']) . "\">" . utf8_encode($row['school_name']) . "</option>";





    }
```

But when ever i select another school. it dont save the value selected to MySql
My guess is it dont mark the value as selected because it get filled dynamic
I now have to change the code so when i select it it must marked is as selected

Comment: where do you store the selected value? For an example if you store the selected value on a variable you can do `<option value="My School"<?php if ($row[school_name] == $var_name) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>My School</option>`

Comment: I updated the Q. thanks for Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a repeated function to compare the value against the row value

```
<?php
    function selected($a, $b) {
        return ($a === $b) ? ' selected' : '';
    }
?>

<option name="school" value="My School" <?= selected($row["school_name"], "My School"); ?>>My School</option>

<option name="school" value="Your School" <?= selected($row["school_name"], "Your School"); ?>>Your School</option>
```

Comment: Check typo of your select tag: "name="school_name"

Comment: OMW... somtimes you just need an extra set of eyes

Comment: Tx the type caused the problem of not saving the field